# Why is this method accepting byte, when it's parameter is double?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, parameters

First, I want to say that this is just a simple code, it's an example and I am studying for a exam.

```
public class TOblik
    {
        public int povrsina = 0;
        public TVrsta vrsta = 0;

        public TOblik(TVrsta a)
        {
        }
    }

    public enum TVrsta
    { 
        Kvadrat,
        Krug
    }

    public class A
    {

        public static double Dodaj(TOblik o, TVrsta v, double r = 0)
        {
            if (v == TVrsta.Kvadrat)
            {
                return o.povrsina + r * r;
            }
            else
            {
                o.vrsta = v;
                return o.povrsina;
            }
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            TOblik oblik = new TOblik(TVrsta.Kvadrat);
            double vrednost = 10;
            byte broj = 5;
            TVrsta vrsta = TVrsta.Krug;

            Dodaj(oblik, vrsta, broj);

            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
```

What I don't get is why is this code working. The method Dodaj last parameter is double, but it is accepting when I forward broj (which type is byte).

Comment: C# **casts** `bytes` **implicitly** to `double`s.

Comment: You can check [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y5b434w4.aspx) for complete table of such conversions.

Comment: Oh yea, my bad, byte is lesser then double, so double is accepting byte. Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

C# has **implicit casts**: data of *some* types can **convert** to data in *other* types without mentioning the conversion (*explicit* conversions also exist like for instance `byte a = (byte) b;` ). Usually implicit casts can only be done when the "*target* type" is more general and thus can handle *all* values of the *source* type.

As you can read in the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y5b434w4.aspx):

> The following table shows the **predefined implicit numeric conversions**.
>   Implicit conversions might occur in many situations, including **method
>   invoking** and assignment statements.
>
> (...)
>
> ```
> From    To
> ------------------------------------------------------------------------
> ...     ...
> byte    short, ushort, int, uint, long, ulong, float, double, or decimal
> ...     ...
> ```

The documentation also warns that conversion from `int` to for instance `float` might result in *precision loss*. So one always has to be a bit careful with these.

You can see that this conversion happens in the `csharp` interactive shell:

```
csharp> byte a = 10;
csharp> double b = a;
csharp> b
10
```

Comment: Thanks for documentation!